# Close one DIV on opening another one

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to achieve is to close one DIV when other DIV is opened (click open) with jQuery. Following is the HTML structure.

I am also interested to know if, in this case multiple DOM elements can be controlled with a single function.

HTML Structure

```
<div class="region-selection">
    <div class="region-search"><h6>REGION</h6></div>
    <div class="region-dropdown"></div>
</div>

<div id="top-login">
    <a href="#" class="top-register"><span>REGISTER</span></a>
    <div class="company-registration-modal"></div>
</div>
```

Here, on clicking the class `.region-search` and its children, I could get the region-dropdown to slide down. I could also get the company registration model to click open as well. However, when the first DIV is active, when I click the second DIV, the first one remains active. I need to close it.

I am also trying to use the same jQuery function to control both DOM. Is it possible?

The jQuery is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $registration_dropdown=$('.company-registration-modal');
    var $registration_link=$('.top-register span, .fa-registered');

    $registration_dropdown.hide();
    $registration_link.on('click touchend', function(event){

        var target = $(event.target);

        if(target.is($registration_link)){
            $registration_dropdown.slideToggle(300);
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest($registration_dropdown).length===0) {
            $($registration_dropdown).slideUp(300);
        }
    });

    $registration_dropdown.mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).delay(400).slideUp(300);
    });

});
```

Similarly, I write a different function for the second DIV.

Comment: Sindico, Could you please help me with this

Comment: I'm confused on what you're trying to hide and show. Do you have multiple 'region-selection' elements?

Comment: Note that your code, as written, slides down and up the empty div below the Register link. You're not showing the other code, so it's kind of difficult to tell how they interact with each other. You could write code that controlled both, but you'd need to change the structure of the HTML and/or add new classes to them.

Comment: Region-dropdown-a child DIV of region selection will be dropped down on clicking h6 element-REGION. The Jquery that I was able to write managed that. Once the cursor mouseout the region dropdown class it closes as well. However, when I click the next div with top login ID to drop it's child DIV-company-registration-model, the first DIV remains open. I am trying to close the region dropdown div as I click on top login to open its child DIV.

Comment: I'm also trying to run a single function to handle both DOM without having to rewrite the codes

Comment: Clearly... This question is *unclear*. See what can be reproduced from the code you provided [HERE](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qavkYm).